# Open up SharePoint Online in a browser as specific user

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, asp.net

I've searched around for solutions to this but haven't found anything so far so thought i'd ask and see if anyone knows.

Essentially, we're trying to intergrate an ASP.net web app with SharePoint Online. Links from the app are to open libraries where users can access documents. Management doesn't want to purchase additional licenses for these users or allow them to use their live IDs to authenticate into our site.

Does anyone know of any methods of opening a new browser window, which is pre authenticated as a user we've created into a particular site? I am guessing using C# CSOM to authenticate into SharePoint Online and then open a site in the browser as said user.

The idea is that this user account would be able to read the documents required and that's it.

Any help appreciated, bit stuck on this one at the moment. Cheers!

Comment: What you're asking to do is a violation of license terms with Microsoft for Office 365. Microsoft licenses individual users, and you're bypassing that by attempting to use a hardcoded user.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase. We've shared out site with an external user account (live ID) who has no license but is allowed by Microsoft's hand to access all content in our site. Is there any way of opening a new browser window, which is pre authenticated as this user into a particular site. I am guessing using C# CSOM to authenticate into SharePoint Online and then open a site in the browser as said user.

Comment: You could try a man-in-the-middle solution where your public server accesses SharePoint and passes the data on. I've used https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO to create a Public API to ListItems, documents need some other handling maybe

Comment: That solution requires an SPO license. If the data comes from or is sent to SPO via say a webpage hosted outside of SPO, the user accessing that page needs an SPO 1 or 2 license. I've been though this with MSFT licensing.

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone!  After some consideration decided instead to go down the path of using a server side helper which grabs anonymous links to these documents using CSOM, then renders them as links on the asp.net web app. Bit more development time but it works.